# WiFi card disappears after reboot, but not after cold boot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, wifi, network-interface

I have an Arch-based server (Zotac Nano, AMD Kabini-based) which doubles as WiFi access point using a miniPCI Atheros WiFi card.

If I start it form cold boot (as in “it was off”), then everything starts and works fine 100% of the time. However, if I then run “reboot” command, then there is 80% chance that then the system is back online, the WiFi card will be gone.

**Here is dmesg after cold boot:**
http://pastebin.com/raw/CGsy9iqX

**and dmesg after reboot:**
http://pastebin.com/raw/61LMJXEG

The card is physically visible regardless, because lspci remains unchanged:
http://pastebin.com/raw/8R2LLTWX

I had this problem since a year now. With every kernel update there was over this period. It is a remote server, so being able to manually turn it in after a shutdown is rarely possible.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from the dmesg it's not setting up the wlan network card at all. Use the command "rfkill list" to see if the card is soft blocked or hard blocked , if it's hard blocked try switching it on from the button otherwise use the command "rfkill unblock wifi".

Comment: Thanks for being the only person who responded. Here's what happens. When the WiFi card works, the 'rfkill list' displays WiFi is not soft- and hard- locked. So no surprise there. 

But here's the kicker: When the computer boots and WiFi does not work, 'rfkill list' does not say it is locked in any way - instead, it does not display any output!